# Is asking for the status of Vandiver's conjecture suitable for MO?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic

I wonder what the current status of Vandiver's conjecture in number theory is? An internet search revealed the paper "Vandiver's conjecture via K-theory" by Alexander Stolin from 2020 on the arxiv where Stolin claims to prove the Vandiver conjecture. However, I didn't find that paper on mathscinet, so it does not seem to be published yet.

Is it suitable for MO to ask about the status of Vandiver's conjecture?

Comment: I don’t think that questions asking about the correctness of papers (especially papers purporting to prove famous conjectures) are on-topic here.

Comment: @Andy Putman: Please note, that I'm not asking about the correctness of Stolin's paper, but the status of the conjecture. Stolin's paper was just the last source I could find that could influence the satus, therefore I mentioned it.

Comment: It’s a famous enough question that if there was serious progress on it, it would not exactly be a secret.  Unless you have some good reason beyond a random preprint to think that there has been progress despite the fact that no one is talking about it, wikipedia hasn’t been updated, etc. then I don’t think MO is the right place for this.

Comment: I agree with Andy on the "it wouldn't be secret knowledge" front. There would be an article in Quanta on it, you can be sure. But thanks for following procedure and asking here if it's suitable for main!